# ArcGis: Count categorical variable per nuts3 by overlapping point-file and polygon-file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, r, overlapping-features

Download from [this website](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0By9u5m3kxn9yfjZtdFZLcW82SWpzT1VwZXE1a3FtRGtSdEl1c1NvY205TGpack9xSFc2T2s&usp=sharing) the **NUTS_RG_60M_2006 files** (shapefile) and the csv-file T_DischargePoints_West.csv ([source](http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/waterbase-uwwtd-urban-waste-water-treatment-directive-4/)) and save them on your computer. Open them through ArcGis and plot xy-points. You get this result:

[image]

The cvs-file contains a number of variables. There is one categorical variable (dcpWaterBodyType). I now would like to know **how many points** from **each** category of dcpWaterBodyType there are **in each nuts3-polygon**. If possible, I also would like to determine automatically what the percentage of points of WaterBodyTypeA, WaterBodyTypeB, WaterBodyTypeC... is in one polygon and this for all the polygons.

Can somebody explain me how to do this in ArcGis or R?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option:

1. Use the [Spatial Join](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/spatial-join.htm) method to join the polygon info to the points
2. Create a new text field in the joined point layer
3. Field calculate/concatenate the dcpWaterBodyType field values with the polygon name or id field
4. Finally, right click on field created in step three and choose the Summarize option

This should produce a count of the various dcpWaterBodyType per polygon feature.